# Windows Server 2008 RAID 1 failed. How do I fix it?

Tags: raid, windows-server-2008

I have two 1.5TB drives, set up via a 4-bay external HDD case. It connects via eSATA and USB 2.0.

I had it configured as a mirrored RAID 1 in Windows Server 2008. I transferred some data to it and powered down the external bay. When I powered it back on, my RAID 1 indicated it had failed and now I imported what was seen as a foreign volume and I am left with 2 simple volumes (both dynamic).

How do I get my RAID 1 back. Do I need to reformat both drives?

Comment: Can someone suggest a good Software Raid solution over the Windows Server 2008 Disk Manager? This would resolve his future issues. I use hardware raids so I am not familiar with the best options in this scenario.